# Google maps link from greasemonkey default zoom

Tags: javascript, google-maps, greasemonkey

Something seems to have changed on google maps recently that changed the default zoom.  I've tried adding zoom=17 and z=17, but nothing seems to change.

I'm just creating a hyperlink on page using the following url & query

"https://maps.google.com/?zoom=17&q=" +myAddress.replace(/ /g, '+');

In the past it's always worked fine no matter what address I used in the query.  Just wondering what may have changed and if I need to work around this another way.

Comment: oddly enough, after a bit more testing, lower values of z work.  0-13, but nothing anymore zoomed than 13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I ended up using to solve the problem.  I can specify zoom by z=16 provided latitude and longitude as Brock explained.

```
addMapLL('900+w+900+s+clearfield+UT');  // just a random address formatted

function addMapLL(address) {
    var api = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=true&address=" + address;

     GM_xmlhttpRequest(
    {
        method: 'GET',
        url: api,
        onload: function(resp) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(resp.responseText);

            if (obj.status == "OK") {
                var lat = obj.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
                var lng = obj.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
                var ll  = "&ll=" + lat + "," + lng;

                // .href is already set as follows
                // https://maps.google.com/?z=16&q=900+w+900+s+clearfield+UT
                document.getElementById('googlemap').href += ll;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Google maps, now, will not zoom past `z=13` unless Latitude and Longitude are also supplied. EG: `&ll=98.414257,-21.727585`.

As a scripter, this makes your task a bit more involved; here is a pseudocode approach that will work:

1. Open the map page as before, but flag it (custom URL param or `GM_setValue`) as first opened by your script.
2. Set the script to also run on Google maps pages.
3. On flagged Google maps pages:

   1. Grab the share link.
   2. Change the `z` parameter only, EG `&z=17`.
   3. Make sure any flag is cleared.
   4. `location.replace()` to the modified share link

---

---

Alternatively, a more durable strategy is to switch to using [the Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/).

Comment: Good to know.  Where did you find the documentation explaining this?

Comment: There is no (public) documentation for this.  Several careful experiments showed the limits and proof-of-concept solution.

Comment: Could I use the API to accomplish the same thing?  I don't want to embed the map on my page.  I would rather have it open in it's own window and still have all the same features as if I just searched for the address.

Comment: The API works on embedded map objects.  You *might* be able to hook into the same functions on the regular map page, but I don't use Google maps enough to know for sure.  Poke around and see what's what.

Answer (score 0):

If you access [Google Maps](https://maps.google.com) and click and share link button you will see something like this:

https://maps.google.com/?ll=53.944771,-0.854187&spn=0.890705,2.694397&t=m&z=9

So i think you should worry about some required field...