# GM_xmlhttpRequest's responsetext is missing some HTML

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, greasemonkey, gm-xmlhttprequest

If I go to [this *Google Maps* page](https://maps.google.com/?q=1093%20W%203090%20S,Syracuse,%20UT), some of the HTML is missing in *View Source*, but shows up in Firebug.

Likewise, when that same URL is passed  to my function, the following HTML does not show up in the `responseText`, but it does show in Firebug when I open the page.

```
<a id="mapmaker-link" class="kd-button mini left" style="" href="https://www.google.com/mapmaker?ll=41.06877,-112.047203&spn=0.038696,0.132093&t=h&z=14&vpsrc=0&q=1093+W+3090+S,Syracuse,+UT&utm_medium=website&utm_campaign=relatedproducts_maps&utm_source=mapseditbutton_normal">
```

Here is the function I'm using:

```
function updateMap(url) {
     GM_xmlhttpRequest(
    {
        method: 'GET',
        url: url,
        onload: function(resp) {
            var ll = resp.responseText.split("mapmaker?")[1];
            ll     = ll.split("&")[0];
            document.getElementById('googlemap').href = url+"&"+ll;
        }
    });
}
```

I have placed a sample `responseText` value at [pastebin.com/Tt8nrzG8](http://pastebin.com/Tt8nrzG8).

Comment: Can you post what's the content of `resp.responseText`?

Comment: https://maps.google.com/?q=1093+W+3090+S,Syracuse,+UT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response is "missing" HTML because the called page loads that HTML (and almost all of the page's content) via AJAX.
`GM_xmlhttpRequest` (and all other current AJAX methods) only gets the static source of a given page.  Such XHR requests cannot process a requested page's javascript, like a browser does when you browse to the page.

In fact, if you save [that sample `responseText`, that you linked,](http://pastebin.com/Tt8nrzG8) as an HTML file; you'll see it looks like this:

[image: The OP's sample response]

---

See ["How to get an AJAX get-request to wait for the page to be rendered before returning a response?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11489451/331508), for the same type of problem.  But note that the answer recommends that you use **an API, if one is available.**

So, use [the Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/) to get the lat/long you want for your URL.

**Or,** the easiest approach is still to have the script also run on Google maps pages and do a one-time zoom on links with your special URL parameter -- like I recommended on [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15843725/331508).  This has the added advantage that no calls to Google are made/needed until you actually decide to click your Google Maps link.

If you *do* opt for the iframe approach (again, NOT recommended for ANY Google site), beware that you will need to [adjust the URL to tell Google to allow iframing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7469997/331508) and the lat/long information will be in a different part of the page.

Comment: Ok, looked around and finally the following link to get a JSON string which contains my Lat and Lng    https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=true&address=